# How to get back Launcher icon for emacs in 16.04?

Tags: launcher, icons, .desktop, emacs

After installing 16.04 the Emacs icon in the Launcher turned into a question mark:

[image]

In 15.10, the icon looked more like this:

[image]

I guess the problem might be that I installed Emacs from source ( and not using `sudo apt-get install emacs24` ). The binaray is now installed in
`/opt/emacs-24.5/bin/emacs`.

I found this tutorial [UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles) for how to create `.desktop` files.

If I run `find /opt/emacs-24.5/ -name '*.desktop'` I get

```
/opt/emacs-24.5/share/emacs/24.5/etc/emacs.desktop
/opt/emacs-24.5/share/applications/emacs.desktop
```

and running `find /opt/emacs-24.5/share/icons -name '*.png'` gives

```
/opt/emacs-24.5/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/emacs.png
/opt/emacs-24.5/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/emacs.png
/opt/emacs-24.5/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/emacs.png
/opt/emacs-24.5/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/emacs.png
/opt/emacs-24.5/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/emacs.png
```

How should I proceed now, to create a working `.desktop` file?

**Update**:

I have now tried the following:

- Copied the supplied `desktop` file that came with `emacs` to a local folder:

  ```
    cp /opt/emacs-24.5/share/applications/emacs.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/emacs.desktop
  ```
- Then changed the icon file name of that file:

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Name=Emacs
  GenericName=Text Editor
  Comment=Edit text
  MimeType=text/english;text/plain;text/x-makefile;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-java;text/x-moc;text/x-pascal;text/x-tcl;text/x-tex;application/x-shellscript;text/x-c;text/x-c++;
  Exec=emacs %F
  Icon=/opt/emacs-24.5/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/emacs.png
  Type=Application
  Terminal=false
  Categories=Development;TextEditor;
  StartupWMClass=Emacs
  Keywords=Text;Editor;
  ```
- Run `desktop-file-validate`:

  ```
   $ desktop-file-validate ~/.local/share/applications/emacs.desktop 
   /home/hakon/.local/share/applications/emacs.desktop: hint: value item "TextEditor" in key "Categories" in group "Desktop Entry" can be extended with another category among the following categories: Utility
  ```
- Run `desktop-file-install`:

  ```
   sudo desktop-file-install --dir=/usr/share/applications/ ~/.local/share/applications/emacs.desktop
  ```

Still the icon did not change. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

1. The `/opt` directory is not in `$PATH`, which makes the `.desktop` file invalid, unless you added the directory manually. Usually applications in `/opt` have an absolute path in their `Exec=` line. Change it to the absolute path to the executable.
2. There might be another `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications`, taking the place of your custom `.desktop` file. Either:

   - drag your home-made `.desktop` file on to the launcher and see if it works (with correct icon).
   - If not, or alternatively, run the command:

     ```
     grep -rl emacs ~/.local/share/applications
     ```

   to find possible outdated or incorrect `.desktop` files, launching `emacs`

Comment: Actually I have added `/opt/emacs-24.5/bin` to `$PATH` in my `~/.bashrc` so I still think it is strange that it required the absolute path

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the problem was not using an absolute path name for the `Exec` key. Here is a modified `/usr/share/applications/emacs.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Emacs
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Edit text
MimeType=text/english;text/plain;text/x-makefile;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-java;text/x-moc;text/x-pascal;text/x-tcl;text/x-tex;application/x-shellscript;text/x-c;text/x-c++;
Exec=/opt/emacs-24.5/bin/emacs %F
Icon=/opt/emacs-24.5/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/emacs.svg
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;TextEditor;
StartupWMClass=Emacs
Keywords=Text;Editor;
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.22
```

This seems to work fine now.

Comment: Ah, crap, just posted my answer while yours popped up... So the first option it was :)